# android : unable to run shell script(.sh) from my application

Tags: android, bash, shell

i am not able to run shell scripts from my application.only "ls -l" and echo commands respond.rest dont seem to do anything.not even "touch" command works.i tried creating a file in sdcard using touch command in my script..only the echo command worked.my shell script is in sdcard too

Comment: What error messages do you get? You may be don't have touch executable on your device at all. Android has a very limited set of binaries... Check which do you have by listing /system/bin

Comment: Give a bit more information. How are you sending commands? adb? Are you developing on Windows, Mac, or Linux?

Answer (score 1):

The sdcard is mounted with noexec. You will have to copy the scripts to the app's local data drive to execute.

You should be able to see the mounted permissions of all file-systems by logging into the phone (adb shell or whatever else) and typing `mount`

Comment: i am building on Ubuntu using eclipse indigo.i successfully made the apk to run my script.it runs the echo command in the script but no other commands.i was able to run "touch" using terminal that successfully executed my .sh from sdcard but unable to execute the same .sh called by app. i am still not sure about ADB thing(i am new at android).is  adb a separate shell ,just like sh,used by apps to run commands???do i have to do modifications to my script to enable that??

Comment: Ok, you're not executing a shell script that resides in the sdcard. You're just running shell commands that write to the sdcard. To write to the sdcard you need the `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` in the manifest. I am not sure if that is what is stopping you though. Can  you post the logcat? Learn about abd [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html)

Comment: Ancantus..I will try that.thanks.I don have ligcat right now.its a query for my team.will get it from them and post :)

Answer (score 0):

The rest of the commands like **"cd"** etc doesnot work in Android as it encounters lot of permission issues.

So the best solution is to trigger **"script manager"**  or **"terminal emulator"** apps already available through your app.